# Photo source file missing or Bogus header data for .bmp images

Tags: shotwell, image-viewers

I am generating an image dataset through a simulator and the files are generated in `.bmp`  format. The simulator is running on Windows and I need to then use the images on Ubuntu 20.04. I will need to do some processing on the images.

Before implementing my pipeline I was going through the image dataset qualitatively, i.e. I was opening random images with the Ubuntu Image viewer and/or with Shotwell viewer. At this point I realized that some of the images do not open and I have the error

`Photo source missing: PATH_TO_THE_IMAGE`

or

`BMP has bogus header data`

**The really strange thing is that I can see all the images fine on Windows. Therefore, this must be an Ubuntu problem in my opinion.**

The version of the software is reported below

- I have Image Viewer 3.36.3
- I have shotwell 0.30.10 – “Celle”
- I am on Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel `5.10.0-1051-oem`

I would like to understand how to solve this issue and if the images are recoverable or not.

Comment: I get the same error when transferring photos to my computer from my camera (Not sure what the fix is yet). How are you transferring the files from your Windows machine to your Linux machine? Perhaps that is the source of the problem?

Comment: I am doing it simply accessing the windows partition from my ubuntu partition (I have a laptop with two partitions, one per OS, ubuntu and windows)